# Chefspec tests for windows machines

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

My chef workstation is on an ubuntu 16.04 machine. Can I run chefSpec tests on my ubuntu workstation for recipes that are intended for windows machines. I know that we can specify the "platform" and "version" in the chefspec test recipe. My question is that can our workstation be an ubuntu machine and the "platform" in the test recipe be windows.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `platform` and `version` config options will set up the needed canned Ohai data to simulate whatever OS you request (no matter what the host is) but some things from Ruby do work differently on Unix and Windows (eg. `File::ALT_SEPARATOR`). This is not generally a big deal though, correctly written unit tests should work on any platform.